# How to add a UITabBarController to window

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Hi GUys I have a window and a tabbar. How do I add all the view controllers to the tabbar and to the window. My Code is here

```
UITabBarController *tab = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UIViewController *first = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *second = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *third = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

//HOW can i add these view controllers to tabbar and hwo to add tabbar to window...


[self.window makeKeyandVisible];
```

Please help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new here but I think this will work. There are plenty of tuts out there too so you might wanna check them out. I'll try to find one for you if I can but I think this will suffice.

```
UITabBarController *tab = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UIViewController *first = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *second = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *third = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

NSArray *tt = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:first, second, third, nil];

tab.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tt]; 

[self.window addSubview:[tab view]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```